# An update values box appears when I use Paste.Special

Tags: excel, vba

I open a file and select a worksheet.  I have material in the copy buffer to paste to it.  The next line does a PasteSpecial to that worksheet but a window pops up to update values with a list of filenames to select from.

The second PasteSpecial call is okay.  The input window's title at the top says
UPDATE VALUES: Ad Spreadsheet Variant.xslx -  which is a version of the workbook created and deleted a week ago.

I went to the data window and removed any dependencies listed in the connections panel so there are no connections.  I have stepped through the code with msgbox calls to see if the error is really not associated with the line of code but comes from somewhere else - but it always happens on that line.

If I click on open in the update values box, nothing happens.

If I click on cancel, the macro continues without error.

I call only one subroutine in this module which checks whether the output file is already open.  I get the same problem in three other modules constructed the same way.  I know everybody hates 'activate' but I'm a beginner (in deep water) and I do what I can.

I line up my input and output files, opened previously - I am just making sure they're accessible. It's not in a loop so the 'activate' time hit is of no concern.

```
Option Explicit

Workbooks(Infilename).Activate
Worksheets(InputSheet).Activate
'I pickup the columns to copy

Columns("B:AO").Select
Selection.Copy

'make sure the output file is lined up
Workbooks(Outfilename).Activate
Worksheets(TargetSheet).Activate

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, 
Operation:=xlNone, _
  SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The results of this are fine except for this hiccup associated with the first `Selection.PasteSpecial` call.

Image of the dialog box that appears

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve As well, be sure to have Option Explicit at the top of the code you edit into the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just put a snippet and don't really expect it to run as a complete unit - and i think the problem may actually be in some sense external to the code itself because the code works - it's just that the window pops up during execution..  But i've edited that statement in.

Answer (score -1):

I tried many things suggested in this and other forums.  But the solution was to unprotect the pages in my spreadsheet, go to 'Connections' on the Data tab, and break all the connections to earlier versions.  How they got connected in the first place, i don't know.  But the other suggestions i followed (examining Conditional Formatting and Data Validation), though they didn't help this problem, have made for better code overall and some new tools to my belt. No more pop-up input requests from nowhere.
Thanks StackOverflow.